# Python: How to insert a line in a function?

Tags: python, insert, line

I'm learning the basics of python and i want to know in this function, how to insert a new line? I know i could have in the function;

```
print(f)
 print(f)
```

But for the sake of this example below, where when calling the function if i wanted to specify how many times to output it. How would i go about making it so there is a new line between each?

I'm suppose to have tried other methods, but as a new learner thats putting the egg before the chicken.

```
enter code here
def do_twice(f):
    print(f)

do_twice("Hello"*2)
```

Comment: You mean `for i in range(2): do_twice("Hello")` ??

Comment: A function called `do_twice` that only does something once?

Answer (score 0):

`'\n'` is the newline character. (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) for more)

So for your example:

```
def do_twice(f):
    print(f)

do_twice("Hello \n"*2)
```

Will print

`Hello`

`Hello`